# Expo test fails after setting up new project

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I've created a new minimal TypeScript project using Expo: `expo init myapp`

After that I `cd myapp` and run `yarn test`.

However, the default test that's included in the project fails with:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

Is this a bug in the Expo app template?

- Expo version: 34.0.1
- Node version: 10.16.3
- Yarn version: 1.17.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is install `jest-expo`

1. You can run `yarn add jest-expo --dev`
2. Then you'll need to add/update `package.json` to include:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "jest"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo"
}
```

4. and add `react-test-renderer` to our project:
5. `yarn add react-test-renderer --dev` or `npm i react-test-renderer
   --save-dev`
6. And then you configure the test.
7. Now run `yarn test` or `npm run test`,

[Useful links](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/testing-with-jest/) with more details

Comment: `jest-expo` is included in the Expo template, as well as the `test` script and the jest `preset` config. So, it might be that `react-test-renderer` should be included in the Expo project template? But I thought it was a secondary dependency, as it appears the App file is built even though it imports `react-test-renderer`?

Comment: @TedNyberg Yes, you can install it, fill out the test syntax and run the test through the command. You can see the link I left in the answer for details.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I think the answer is that the Expo project template is incomplete - that additional work is required to make the test run after running `expo init`?

Comment: @TedNyberg Yes, the module installation and configuration required for testing at the current Expo is required.